# How to build docker image without having to use the sudo keyword

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm building a node.js app which allows people to run code on my server and I'm using Docker to containerise the user's code so that it can't steal data or in general do something they shouldn't. I have a Docker image template that is copied into the user's personal app directory and I want to build the image using this function I've written:

```
const util = require("util");
const exec = util.promisify(require("child_process").exec);

async function buildContainer(path, dockerUser) {
    return await exec(`sudo docker build -t user_app_${dockerUser} ${path}`);
}
```

However when I go to use it, it requires me to enter my sudo password as if I was executing it manually in a terminal window.

Is there anyway I can run this function without having to include the `sudo` keyword?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Comment: Actually I just found the answer to my own question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo#:~:text=If%20you%20don't%20want,writable%20by%20the%20docker%20group.

Comment: Note that the code you have here is incredibly dangerous: if the user is able to control either the `dockerUser` or `path` environment variable, and knows they have `sudo` access, they can run any command as root and thereby take over the host.  At the very least, pass the command as an array of words, or better, use a [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) instead of shelling out to `docker`.  (You'll still need permission to access the Docker socket, and careless container setup can still root the host.)

Comment: The user doesn't have access to either variable, the `dockerUser` and `path` variables are generated server side using the app's MongoDB ID from its document in the collection so it should be ok. I'm using the dockerode npm package to manage the containers however

Answer (score 0):

you can use podman instead of docker.
There you don´t need sudo.
You have the most commands like docker.
example:

```
podman build
podman run
```

and so on...

hope that helps :)

Regards